# Populating AspNetUserLogins and AspNetUserTokens

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I've tried quite a few examples from the internet (e.g. [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901894/2725524), [second](https://logcorner.com/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-core/) and others) and everything works fine except the fact that tables AspNetUserLogins and AspNetUserTokens don't show any data after successful login and token generation.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any social logins in your app?

Comment: No, the comment below, made it clear!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The table `AspNetUserTokens` is for external authentication token storage and is filled by `SignInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync` method. Internal authentication tokens are stored in memory by default and if you want to store them into the database, you must create your own table and your own logic to store.

Comment: Ohhh, ok, that makes sense! I'm not using any external authentication, yet. And the AspNetUserLogins?

Comment: It is for external login too. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155447/the-aspnetuserlogins-table-identity