# Asp.Net Core Identity: GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync not creating AspNetUserTokens record

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm generating phone number token using `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync()` after creating the user using UserManager. I consistently see that `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync()` does not create a record in *AspNetUserTokens* table even though the token is generated. Phone verification fails because of this.

I also call `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync()` to verify the email. But email verification is successful even though there is no record in *AspNetUserTokens* table. Can anyone shed light on why GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync not persisting AspNetUserTokens
record?

Platform: .Net 5

Snippet below:

```
using (var scope = TransactionUtil.CreateAsyncTransactionScope())
{

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, createUserDto.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to create account");
    }

    // Business logic removed for clarity

    scope.Complete();
}
await SendConfirmEmailAsync(user);
await SendPhoneNumberTokenAsync(user);


private async Task SendConfirmEmailAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

    // Send EMail
}

private async Task SendPhoneNumberTokenAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    if(user == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneNumber) || user.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        return;

    var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, user.PhoneNumber);

    // Send SMS
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: added code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think we might have a little misunderstood here...

Both `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` and `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` won't storing anything up to database.

As the code implementation that `userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` would call to `GenerateUserTokenAsync` as we can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1534), that's the same method `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` would call (only difference in params).

`GenerateUserTokenAsync` then call to [GenerateAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L1758) method that both `PhoneNumberTokenProvider` and `EmailTokenProvider` was just simply take from the base class [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs#L58), which again, not storing anything up to database, we can check `manager.CreateSecurityTokenAsync` method [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2380) if having any doubt.

The `AspNetUserTokens` token that mentioned above (which i believe was implemented on EF) was designed to store informations about external authentication token storage, which was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200884/populating-aspnetuserlogins-and-aspnetusertokens).