# ASP.NET Identity tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

This might be a stupid question but I'm learning ASP.NET and now focusing on the back-end. The scaffolded identity tables that we get confuse me a little. What is the meaning/use of each table?

For example:

- `Users` table: for users info like email, name and so on.
- `Roles` table: has record of each available role available in the app.
- `UserRoles`: shows which users has what roles.

But what about the rest?

- User Claims
- User Logins
- Role Claims
- User Tokens

Can anyone explain what they are used for? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User Claims:**  A User Claim is a statement about a User, represents a claim that a user possesses.

**Role Claims:**    A Role Claim is a statement about a Role. When a user is a member of a role, they automatically inherit the role’s claims, represents a claim that's granted to all users within a role.

**User Logins:** hold information about 3rd party/external logins.

**User Tokens:** for external authentication token storage

You can have a look at [The AspNetUserLogins table Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155447/the-aspnetuserlogins-table-identity)  and [AspNetUserTokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200884/populating-aspnetuserlogins-and-aspnetusertokens) , [The Identity model
Entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-identity-model) to know more.